# aptana cannot open project on network drive from mac

Tags: macos, networking, project, aptana, drive

When I try to open my project I get this error message:

The project description file (.project) for 'project name' is missing.  This file contains important information about the project.  The project will not function properly until this file is restored.

I am using a mac (OS 10.8.2), the project code php files reside on a network drive not my local drive.

How should I set up my project so I don't get these sorts of errors?
A bit of background:
 - last week I was not getting this error, this monday morning I am, last week I upgraded my mac OS so maybe something happened there or maybe it has something to do with the fact that I'm connecting by wifi now and maybe last week I wasn't, I'm not sure.

Ideally I guess I would just run a local copy off my local drive and then push my code changes thorough git to the communal dev server before pushing to production but that's not how we do things and I'm not sure how to set all that up anyway  - also the site is so involved it might be a real challenge to get everything working from local.

So, how do I set up my aptana project so it reads the code from the network drive while the project setting files reside locally?

Thanks

Comment: what kind of network drive, and did you remember to reconnect to it?

Comment: the network drive uses linux.  I can connect to the network drive to open files in aptana but it does not seem to recognize the .project file.   It opens it as a file not as a project.  When I just hit the Open Project menu item I get the error message above.

Comment: I see the project location (under project properties) is given as "/Volumes/www/html/projname"  but when I look at the folder with finder it is listed as "/Volumes/www-1/html/projname" - so maybe the problem is that now that I am connecting with wifi the "-1" is added so now aptaa can't find it anymore.   So how can I fix this?  is there an aptana project file I can edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, nevermind,  instead of fixing the broken links I just import the folder as a new project and now it works as before.